# How to set up a connection for two virtual machines on the same host, as well as provide them with Internet access and SSH connection?

Tags: ssh

I need to organize a connection between two virtual machines that are running on the same PC.

Also, each guest system must have access to the Internet and the ability to connect via ssh from the host to the virtual machine.

Virtual machines have static ip addresses: vs1 - 192.168.100.10\16 , vs2 - 172.24.116.8\12. For deployment of virtual machines I use VirtualBox and Win11.

Which of the available methods can I use?

I'm already confused about NAT, Briged Network, HO adapter, etc.